# What is the deal with "two colour mode"?

Tags: fractal

In Fractal, once you get to level five you get a message stating that "two colour mode is activated" and unsurprisingly you now have fractals of two different colours on the board;

[image]

Apart from these additional fractals being different colours, they also don't appear to follow the previously established rules regarding the creation of blooms in that you can now create a cluster of 7 fractals without these being removed from the board;

[image]

What is the deal with "two colour mode"?

Comment: I think each bloom has to be entirely one color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two colour mode changes a couple of the objectives. Firstly, fractals of each different colour will only bloom with fractals of the same colour. This leads to a requirement of carefully choosing which fractals to push to ensure that you don't end up in a situation where you cannot bloom.

Secondly, fractals of either colour will spawn when you bloom, regardless of the colour of the bloom.

Finally, fractals that you push onto the board can be of either colour, and the colour of the next fractal that will be pushed is detailed in the bottom right corner next to the remaining pushes counter;

[image]